# Editing curved annotation - unable to add vertex to baseline sketch, move bezier curve handles independently

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, annotation

It appears as though I am unable to add a vertex to a curved annotation during an editing session in ArcMap. When the annotation is right-clicked, the box to add or delete a vertex appears, but the options are greyed out.

While also on the curved annotation editing question - is it possible to move the bezier curve handles independently of one another? When I move one, the opposite handle moves as well and changes the baseline on both sides of the vertex.

It would be quicker to just re-do the smaller annotations, but sometimes my job involves editing long, meandering text strings and it is nice to avoid awkward gaps that result from certain curves.

*edit* - It appears that it is only the annotations in this specific map document, as the annotations can be edited in any other .mxds which means this problem will probably never get get figured out.

[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.  Here you seem to be asking about two but for one maybe you are just making a comment.  In either event I think you should make clear what the single question you want to ask is and remove references to the other.